# How to clear Sprockets cache?

Tags: sprockets

When a Sprockets object compilation fails (due to a syntax error in CoffeeScript or SASS), it cannot recompile after the error is fixed because it says "file is already required."

In order to get the Sprockets object to work, I have to destroy and re-create it. I was wondering if anyone knew if there was a way to tell the Sprocket object to internally reset itself as to not run into this issue.

Comment: Is this in development mode or in an environment where you're using precompiled assets?

Answer (score 36):

[`rake tmp:cache:clear`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#tmp) deletes the temporary cache directory.

Comment: Does not clean sprocket cache. Files under `./tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/` still exist.

Comment: What about `rake assets:clobber`? That is a recent addition and might only be available in Rails 4.

Comment: Aha. If you want a more targeted version, `rake tmp:clear:cache` deletes `tmp/cache`. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#tmp

Answer (score 10):

In my case, the following command worked:

```
rake tmp:clear
```

Comment: This is a broader "clear" than just the assets/Sprockets cache. According to the [`tmp` docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#tmp): "rake tmp:clear clears all the three: cache, sessions and sockets".

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
Rails.application.assets.cache.clear
```

but [this method](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/5c2021f69c2820044ed4d29e1fab85c34306efd3/lib/sprockets/cache.rb#L156) only in master branch and not even in [beta](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/ad8e23c91cf42f57b4d7ad3fe7d9a74c8139cc8e/lib/sprockets/cache.rb#L143).

Update: added in [4.0.0.beta5](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/v4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/cache.rb#L153).