# Ruby on Rails: Ran rake assets:precompile and now both local and heroku deployment don't include bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, precompiled

I was having issues deploying my project to a heroku server (Precompile fail). So I found this response, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13713753/2989437, and followed up on the advice. I added one line to my application.rb file:

application.rb

```
module FirstEdc
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false # I added this line
  ...
 end
end
```

I then ran the precompile command, committed the changes, and managed to deploy successfully to heroku. However, now my bootstrap/css appears to have stopped functioning both on the heroku deployment, and my local deployment.

I learned that I was supposed to add another line to my deployment.rb file:

deployment.rb

```
FirstEdc::Application.configure do
  ...

  # Allows for local precompilling --added by Ian
  config.assets.prefix = '/dev-assets'
end
```

So I added this, recompiled and redeployed, but to no avail.

Finally, I ran a rake assets:clean in an attempt to at least get my local deployment back to normal, but it did not work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm reading more into the asset pipeline now, but I feel like this could be a cache problem or something. I'll update as I figure out what's going on.

**edit.** Just to clarify, I've tried removing both additions, running a rake assets:clean and rake assets:clean:all, but neither fix my local deployment.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? `initialize_on_precompile` has no effect in Rails 4.

Comment: `assets:clean` does clear precompiled assets, but Sprockets keeps a cache that you can try clearing as well. Use `rake tmp:cache:clear`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246585/how-to-clear-sprockets-cache/13503672#13503672

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `config.assets.prefix` in any of my apps and they work just fine with Heroku, so not sure what that's doing.

Try removing that line, then running `rake assets:clean`.  Now your local server should be using the files as you change them.  When you want to push, run `rake assets:precompile` first, then push.

If you want to make changes locally after that, run `rake assets:clean` again to get rid of the precompiled files on your local machine.

Comment: I removed both of the additions, and tried rake assets:clean, but my bootstrap still doesn’t work. I can deploy now, which is a plus, but I'm not sure how to get my bootstrap functional again. I added the gem 'bootstrap_helper', but it didn’t help either.

Comment: Don't remove the first addition.  Keep `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`

Comment: Well, keeping config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false allows for me to push to heroku, and thats great. However my bootstrap is still not working on either local, or production.

Answer (score 0):

If Heroku detects any files in `public/assets` it will not attempt to precompile your assets again.  This is by design.

So, you need to make a decision to either always precompile your assets with `rake assets:precompile`, or remove any files in `public/assets` before pushing to Heroku.

*(The recommended way is to allow Heroku to precompile them during push)*

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would you have any insight as to why my bootstrap stopped working? Thanks again.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "stopped working"?  Is it not picking up the bootstrap assets?  Are you getting an error?