# Rails: Bootstrap stopped working after a precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

For some reason my bootstrap broke after I precompiled my code. This started because I couldn't push to heroku because of a precompile error.

So here are the contents of my `application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap3
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require_tree .
```

Maybe the order is wrong? I just added `.../dropdown` hoping it would help, but it did not. I just realized I can actually remove both bootstrap lines without affecting my resulting site.

For my gems, I have:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', "~>3.0.3.0"
...
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
```

Here is a link to my other question, which is similar but less focused: [Ruby on Rails: Ran rake assets:precompile and now both local and heroku deployment don't include bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685924/ruby-on-rails-ran-rake-assetsprecompile-and-now-both-local-and-heroku-deployme)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm getting pretty frustrated, it's been several days of failed action.

Comment: Can you define "stopped working"? Do you mean the static files aren't being precompiled? Or that they aren't being included in your pages? Or something else?

Comment: Well, for one the drop down menu I had at the top of the screen is gone. And the navigation items that used to be horizontal are now vertical with each other. Another example would be how the input boxes for login information no longer highlight in a light blue when selected, or red if the incorrect info is entered. Everything is far more bland than before.

Comment: The blandness is likely the result of stylesheets either not being included in your templates *or* the result of the stylesheets not being found. Use your browser developer tools to check for the existence of tags and/or the possibility of 404's.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that does appear to be the problem. I'm not sure why they would all of the sudden not be included in the project, but I'll do some google searching and see what turns up.

Comment: Edit. Nevermind, I've got some looking around to do... The stylesheets appear to be working, just not in every case. Damn it.