# Clear sprockets cache before rspec test runs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sprockets

In my Rails app, I'm dynamically modifying an `app/assets/stylesheets/main.scss.erb` file for some RSpec tests.  If I run the RSpec tests individually, they all pass fine.  If I run them together, every test fails except the first one.  I suspect sprockets is caching the initial change, which lets the first test pass, but never updates the cache for the subsequent tests.

Is there a way to clear the sprockets cache (I'm using sprockets 3.7.2) before each test executes and force it to reload from the current state of the files?

**Update 12/12/2018:** Here's a little more context about what I'm doing.  I have a Rails engine that powers several applications in my company.  The engine loads a stylesheet inside the engine and it also looks inside the host Rails application and loads a second stylesheet (i.e. we don't require the Rails apps to add the stylesheet to the application.css manifest file themselves; the engine handles it). We recently found a bug that prevented the engine from loading the application level stylesheet, so I fixed it and started adding some tests in the engine. My first attempt at testing was to create a page that had some special divs.  The divs use CSS IDs that are defined in the various stylesheets.  If the divs end up with the expected styles, I know they only got those styles from the stylesheets (which confirms that they got loaded).  This strategy works, but it requires code spread out in the engine and dummy application (inside the engine).  I then started experimenting with having the tests dynamically append CSS rules into the stylesheets when each test is executed.  This strategy is a big improvement because it keeps all the interesting code in the test.  Anyone reading a specific test can immediately see the styles that are being added, and the files that are being modified. Everything is contained in the test.  Unfortunately, even though I'm resetting all the necessary files between tests, it looks like the assets cache isn't getting invalidated.

Comment: It appears that a similar question was answered already: [How to clear Sprockets cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246585/how-to-clear-sprockets-cache). I would try putting `Rails.application.assets.cache.clear` in a before block.

Comment: Unfortunately, that method only works for the unreleased Sprockets 4.

Comment: My bad. I thought that version number was referring to Rails.

Comment: I must admit, I'm fascinated by your use case. In 7 years of developing Rails apps, I've never run across a need to dynamically modify my SCSS. Why are you doing this? (I ask because I'm a firm believer that if it's hard to test, you're probably going about it the wrong way.)

Comment: I added some backstory to the question.

Comment: Could you shell out to call one of the rake tasks mentioned in [How to clear Sprockets cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246585/how-to-clear-sprockets-cache)?

Comment: I tried a couple of the various rake tasks but none seemed to work.  It's removing the files, but I suspect it's holding onto something in memory.